# "Speak to the jarl of Falkreath" still on my journal

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I still have this quest on my journal and I can't seem to "finish" it. My character is already Thane of Falkreath and sided with the Stormcloacks during the Civil War. Truth is, I can't remember very well if I made a mistake or something in the past because I don't have my previous save files, only the one I'm currently playing.

I tried to "finish" this quest by buying and building Lakeview Manor but it didn't work. Any help with this, please? I just don't like having "unfinished" business on my journal.

Comment: I replicated this using by getting the letter requesting me to speak before I went there and absentmindedly forgetting to read it until going through my things to put them away in my new house at Lakeside Manor.  Yeah this quest is buggy.  They clearly didn't test it for out of order completion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [UESP](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Lakeview_Manor):

> - This bug is fixed by version 2.0.5 of the Unofficial Hearthfire Patch.
> - You can fix this using the console command: `SetObjectiveCompleted BYOHHouseFalkreath 15 1`.

Note that the Unofficial Hearthfire Patch has since been rolled into the Unofficial [Legendary](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214/) and [Special Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266) Patches, so this fix should now be available by installing one of those.  Also note that many Unofficial Patch fixes only work when creating a new save (so you should use the console command if the patch does not work).

Comment: I had to use the console command even though I have the patch, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it happens, and if it does it won't go away unless you reload a save from before, or make a new character.

Comment: I've seen at least three circumstances that cause this.  Both can be cleared with console commands.

1. If you get a bad relationship with the Jarl after you receive the letter. 
2. If the Jarl changes before you report.
3. If you receive the letter before becoming Thane of Falkreath but read it after. 
4. If you fail to reply to the appropriate prompt to report, and become thane anyway.

These are all cases where the question should clear (fail in 1, neutral in 2, succeed in 3 and 4.) but doesn't due to poor coding.